# Accessing VARCHAR as BINARY during read with Entity Framework and MySQL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, entity-framework, character-encoding

## The base of the problem:

*Pun intended.*

The problem starts with a very old dBase database where the textual information is encoded directly into [DOS Cyrillic (CP-866)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_866), and because that's not enough of a problem, it's also being transferred to a MySQL database every evening, to which I have access.

I've installed the MySQL Providers and connected to the database with Entity Framework, which was my main data access method, and then for experimental reasons with pure ADO.NET as well.

Everything was going better than expected until I attempted to convert the supposedly *CP-866* values from the database to *UTF-8*, like so:

```
var cp866 = Encoding.GetEncoding(866);
var utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;

string source = "some unreadable set of characters from the database";
byte[] cp866bytes = cp866.GetBytes(source);
byte[] utf8bytes = Encoding.Convert(cp866, utf8, cp866bytes);
string result = utf8.GetString(utf8bytes);
```

I've read it once with EntityFramework and once with ADO.NET with the same result.

For unknown at the time **and less-unknown now** reasons, **it didn't work**. After reading some important articles about encoding and string values I've determined that it is not possible to apply such conversions to the string equivalent of the varchar field in the database because of the nature of the string variable itself.

Few keyboard bangs later, I've finally made it happen by using ADO.NET MySQL Provider and customizing my query by adding **CONVERT(varcharColumn, Binary)** to the column I was testing with.

From then on, I used the above code with the only difference that I already had the cp866 byte array from the convert. I originally intended to do something similar but the MySQL provider wasn't able to directly read bytes from a varchar field, neither I found a way to do it with Entity Framework.

Yes, it works, but it doesn't feel right even to my unexperienced self.

---

## Questions:

**1: Can I specify how Entity Framework should select specific fields?**

I would like to somehow explain my beloved ORM that it should be converting specific varchar fields to binary during the read, without returning the string representation at all, because it messes everything up.

**2: Is there a way to make the ADO.NET MySQL provider to get the bytes of a varchar field, without pulling it as a string first?**

The GetBytes method throws an exception when used with varchar, and the GetSqlBytes method that is normally present in ADO.NET provider is missing in the MySQL version. I don't really want to write Binary Convert on every field which I need to read properly.

**3: Bonus Question: Is it possible to read the CP-866 encoded varchar field as a string as I did, but this time properly changing the encoding to UTF-8?**

There is still a lot of chaos in my head on the encoding topic after today's reading. I still believe there might be something I am missing and that is possible to read a string from the cp-866 encoded varchar fields, like:

```
string cp866EncodedValue = "Œ€„‹… Œ‹€„…Ž‚€ Šš…‚€"; //actual copy-pasted value
```

..and then convert it to UTF-8, while having in mind the field in the database was encoded with CP-866. From what I've read, as soon as it's in a string, it's unicode and the string is immutable. I've tried getting it's byre array representation, changing it to cp866, then to utf8, I tried using it as it is cp866 itself, but without success.

Comment: MySQL [supports](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/charset-charsets.html) CP-866 natively; if set up correctly, it can convert to UTF-8 for you (upon either data insertion or retrieval, as you wish).  Chances are that the character set of the connection over which you originally inserted the data was incorrect, which has led to storage of bad data in the table: you can quickly verify this manually with e.g. `SELECT HEX(mycolumn) FROM mytable`.

Comment: Is that setting from the server or is it being setup through the connection string? I tried setting charset option on the connection string without success. I haven't deal with the data insertion, it's another team that was importing from some dBase databases in another company.

Comment: The driver will request the desired character set upon connection to the server; it *may* be possible to inform the driver of the desired character set in the DSN, but one can *always* change the configuration after connecting using a suitable command e.g. `SET NAMES`.  See [Connection Character Sets and Collations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/charset-connection.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First of all** I would check the current encodings on your database and/or for your table in question.

@eggyal points to the link, where there are these commands for **setting** certain variables:

```
SET character_set_client = charset_name;
SET character_set_results = charset_name;
SET character_set_connection = charset_name;
```

To check these, please use the followings:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set_client';
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set_results';
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set_connection';
```

Then for the default character encoding of the database, use:

```
SHOW CREATE DATABASE databaseName;
```

Then for that specific table, please check:

```
show create table TABLE_IN_QUESTION;
```

---

**After these** you know, which are the exact encodings of your database and/or table in count.

---

**My solution to fix the found issues** is just a link to an interesting source. Please, have a look if this post has something relevant to tell about:

http://nicj.net/mysql-converting-an-incorrect-latin1-column-to-utf8/

---

**PS. *Yes***, I can read the url, it states convertion latin1 -> utf8, but for my understanding same tips will apply to other pairs of character encodings as well.

Comment: **PPS. *Yes**, I also found out you had some specific, numbered questions and you ask for canonical answer (to them). I had this in mind, and tried to answer to the real problem behind instead of sticking to ready directions what to tell. Maybe this is only good approach. I do hope so.*

Comment: The problem is that I don't have access to the configuration of the database. It's being wiped out daily and recreated from the dBase one. I'll have to escalate the problem to other people for these and I am not sure that they are willing to help.

Comment: Well, if you have a console access to database, the "first of all"-part of my answer still applies. Or you don't have even that?

Comment: Also my solution includes query like: `SELECT city, CONVERT(CAST(city as BINARY) USING utf8) FROM MyTable` which may be usefull, if you can drive it through c# code. Of course, check the namings to be same as in your case, this is direct copy paste.

Comment: The variables return utf8, but the "SHOW CREATE DATABASE" returns latin 1. I already did something similar to your suggestions as I pointed out, so I am not willing to go back through my queries and change the code. Converting during the select is what I wanted to avoid because now I have like 30 converts in a single query. Altering any configurations or tables is out of the questions unfortunately, but your answer have been helpful nevertheless.

Comment: The timer is up for the bounty and I have to award it or it goes to waste, I am awarding it to you as you are the only one who tried to answer, even though your answer is not applicable in my situation due to lack of superior access, it's still relevant. Thanks again.